Fine tuning LayoutLmv3 using Cord-V2 dataset
I'm working on fine-tuning LayoutLMv3 using the CORD-v2 dataset. I'm struggling with the data preprocessing part, specifically on how to correctly extract the total amount (TTC) from the images. The examples I've found online seem to use the older CORD dataset, which has a different format. The new CORD-v2 dataset only includes images and ground truth labels.
How to approach this?
I've tried examples from YouTube and Hugging Face but haven't had any success.

I found a solution, you should create a label map for the data you want to extract, then Scale Bounding Boxes after that, and Detect Currency in Text because the problem is the dataset has a lot of different currencies and languages also so this is what I did
label_map = {
"total.total_price": 1,
"other": 0
}
def scale_bbox(box, original_size, target_size=(1000, 1000)):
    x_scale = target_size[0] / original_size[0]
    y_scale = target_size[1] / original_size[1]
    return [int(box[0] * x_scale), int(box[1] * y_scale), int(box[2] * x_scale), int(box[3] * y_scale)]

def detect_currency(text):
    currency_symbols = {
        '$': 'USD',
        '€': 'EUR',
        '£': 'GBP',
        '¥': 'JPY',
        '₹': 'INR',
        '₩': 'KRW',
    }
    for symbol, currency in currency_symbols.items():
        if symbol in text:
            return currency
    return None

def preprocess_data(examples):
    images = []
    words = []
    boxes = []
    labels = []
    original_size = (224, 224)
    currency_converter = CurrencyRates()

    for image, gt in zip(examples['image'], examples['ground_truth']):
        img = image.convert("RGB").resize(original_size)
        images.append(img)
        gt = json.loads(gt)
        batch_words = []
        batch_boxes = []
        batch_labels = []

        for item in gt['valid_line']:
            for w in item['words']:
                text = w['text']
                quad = w['quad']
                bbox = scale_bbox([quad['x1'], quad['y1'], quad['x3'], quad['y3']], original_size)
                bbox = [min(max(0, coord), 1000) for coord in bbox]
                batch_words.append(text)
                batch_boxes.append(bbox)
                if item['category'] == 'total.total_price':
                    try:
                        total_amount_match = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d{2}", text)
                        if total_amount_match:
                            total_amount = float(total_amount_match[0])
                            detected_currency = detect_currency(text)
                            if detected_currency and detected_currency != 'USD':
                                total_amount = currency_converter.convert(detected_currency, 'USD', total_amount)
                            text = f"{total_amount:.2f} USD"
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error processing text: {e}")
                    batch_labels.append(label_map["total.total_price"])
                else:
                    batch_labels.append(label_map["other"])

        words.append(batch_words)
        boxes.append(batch_boxes)
        labels.append(batch_labels)

    encoding = processor(images, words, boxes=boxes, word_labels=labels, truncation=True, padding="max_length", max_length=512, return_tensors="pt")
    return encoding`enter code here`


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I have a similar problem. I am stuck at creating the Custom Dataset. I have labeled 6 delivery receipts with 3 labels in Label Studio (only testing purposes to set up the pipeline). Exported the JSON from it, created programmatically one .JSON file for each data entry from the export. Now I followed all the way up until the end of this youtube video, but unfortunately I am also stuck at the "out of index" problem :/
If I print my datasets then they are not empty, so my problem is to understand where the out of index error actually comes from!
This is the stack trace after running trainer.train()
Currently training with a batch size of: 1
The following columns in the training set don't have a corresponding argument in `VisionEncoderDecoderModel.forward` and have been ignored: image_path, ground_truth_string, annotation_path. If image_path, ground_truth_string, annotation_path are not expected by `VisionEncoderDecoderModel.forward`,  you can safely ignore this message.
***** Running training *****
  Num examples = 5
  Num Epochs = 1
  Instantaneous batch size per device = 1
  Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 1
  Gradient Accumulation steps = 1
  Total optimization steps = 5
  Number of trainable parameters = 201,121,912
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-160-3435b262f1ae> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 trainer.train()

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/table.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    122         return pa.Table.from_batches(
    123             [
--> 124                 self._batches[batch_idx].slice(i - self._offsets[batch_idx], 1)
    125                 for batch_idx, i in zip(batch_indices, indices)
    126             ],

IndexError: list index out of range

Here is my code for the dataset, adapted to CORD-V2:
import json

KEY_START = "<key_start>"
KEY_END = "<key_end>"
VALUE_START = "<value_start>"
VALUE_END = "<value_end>"

def parse_json(batch):

    batch_data = []
    image_path = []

    for filename in batch["annotation_path"]:
        with open(filename) as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)
        
        x_values, y_values, width_values, height_values, labels, texts = [], [], [], [], [], []

        # Extract the values from the JSON structure
        for annotation in data['annotations']:
            for result in annotation['result']:
                value = result['value']
                x_values.append(value['x'])
                y_values.append(value['y'])
                width_values.append(value['width'])
                height_values.append(value['height'])
                labels.append(value['rectanglelabels'][0])  # Assuming each label list contains one item
                texts.append(value.get('text', ''))  # Extract the associated text if available

        x_values = list(map(str, x_values))
        y_values = list(map(str, y_values))
        width_values = list(map(str, width_values))
        height_values = list(map(str, height_values))
        labels = list(map(str, labels))
        texts = list(map(str, texts))

        ground_truth_string = ""
        for label, text in zip(labels, texts):
            ground_truth_string += f"{KEY_START}{label}{KEY_END}{VALUE_START}{text}{VALUE_END}"

        batch_data.append(ground_truth_string)
        print(f"batch_data: {batch_data}")
        file_id = Path(filename).stem
        print(Path(filename))
        print(file_id)
        image_path.append(str(images_dir / f"{file_id}.png"))
        print(f"image_path len: {len(image_path)}")

    return {
        "ground_truth_string":batch_data,
        "image_path":image_path}

